# Move documents to SharePoint 2013 using SSIS WebDav

Tags: sharepoint, ssis, webdav

I have an SSIS package that calls a .jar that exports a file from one system to a specified file path. For my filepath I use \sharepointserver\davwwwroot\library. The problem is I have to have an RDP session open and maintain my file server connection in order for this to work. It will fail without the RDP session and even the davwwwroot connection times out, requiring me to logoff, back on and browse again.

How can I get this process to work without the RDP session?

Comment: Can you provide more iformation. How does it fail - what is the error? The RDP session is from where to where? Have you tried mapping a drive beforehand with `NET USE` just to establish a network connection? You don't even need to use the mapped drive.

Comment: I haven't tried mapping a drive. I'll try that. I can't recall the error. I'll write it down next time. I've seen before where webdav times out after a certain period of time. Maybe if I go the mapped drive route it will initiate a new connection each time.